# Unable to remove element loaded by AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to remove an element on AJAX success which was loaded and attached to the document during a previous AJAX call.

My code looks something like this:

```js
$("#jobs-table-body").on("click", ".one-rc-button", function() {
    var ctx = $.parseJSON($(this).siblings(".context").html());

    $("#one-rc-candidate-id").val(ctx.candidateId);
    $("#one-rc-job-id").val(ctx.jobId);

    var loader = $("#wrapper").loader();

    $.post($("#one-rc-form").attr("action"), $("#one-rc-form").serialize(), function(result) {
        loader.remove();
        if(result.success) {

            // This works and returns 1
            alert($("#candidate-row-" + result.rejectedCandidateId).length);

            // This doesn't seem to be doing anything
            $("#candidate-row-" + result.rejectedCandidateId).remove();
        } else {
            //$("#one-jc-messages").html(result.error);
        }
    });
});
```

The elements `.one-rc-button` and `#candidate-row-<candidateId>` were loaded by a previous AJAX call and they are attached to the document as I can very well see them on my page.

Now, on click of the previously generated `.one-rc-button`, I trigger a second AJAX call (which works fine) and on `result.success`, I want to delete the `#candidate-row-<candidateId>` (which is within the previously generated parent element).

The alert works and returns `1`. So I know for sure that the selector is fine and it is matching one unique element.

What I don't understand is why it is unable to remove the element from the page.

### Observations

1. I use Firefox 10.0.2 where this problem is reproducible.
2. On IE 8, it works (element gets removed)
3. On debugging the script on Firebug, I can verify that I have got a handle to the right eleemnt.

Comment: Check the length once more. I'm sure it will 0 after the `remove`.

Comment: @gdoron I just tried. It stays `1`.

Comment: Well what kind of element is it???

Comment: It's a `<div/>` with some more markup inside it.

Comment: Another update is that I'm able to do `.hide()` successfully. Just `.remove()` isn't working.

Comment: Try `$(...).empty().remove()`. It's very weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by a really ugly workaround. I am still not sure what causes this behaviour.

```js
if(result.success) {
    var removeThis = $("#candidate-row-" + result.rejectedCandidateId);
    removeThis.remove();
    removeThis = $("#candidate-row-" + result.rejectedCandidateId);
    if(removeThis.length != 0) {
        removeThis.remove();
    }
}
```

Now it works on both Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FireBug to set a breakpoint on that line so you can see exactly what it's getting from that selector. Ideally break up the statement first, like this:

```
var unwantedDiv = $("#candidate-row-" + result.rejectedCandidateId);
unwantedDiv.remove(); // <-- Set a breakpoint on this line
```

You can then look at the unwantedDiv variable in the watch pane on the right of the firebug debugger and see what it is, what methods it has/has not got etc. I would assume that you are not getting back exactly what you think you are, possibly because of how you attached the div after the previous AJAX call. More information about JavaScript debugging with FireBug [here](http://getfirebug.com/javascript).

Another option is to turn on strict warnings in the firebug console and see if you get any 'undefined method' errors, which don't stop the show on FireFox, but just bounce you out of that function. Do you get an error in IE?

Comment: Just set the breakpoint and investigated. Turns out, I am getting the right element. Well, I just tested on IE 8 and it successfully removes there. I am using FF 10.0.1

Comment: Strange. Do you get any warning with strict warnings turned on?

Comment: Gah! Silent failure - we must have sinned in a past life. What happens if you try unwantedDiv.empty().remove(); ?